# Turning HTML tag for anchor text into hyperlinks in gmail

Tags: html, tags, gmail, anchor

The gmail email body contains html tag for hyperlinks which is e.g.

```
<a  href=" https://www.w3schools.com"> Visit W3Schools.com! </a>
```

but it does not turn into an anchor text with hyper link. Rather only the URL is hyperlinked.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean

Comment: Please refresh the web page I  have changed the question.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. Generally, a hyperlink would be written like this: `<a href="http://google.com">#SomeText</a>`

Comment: Also, the gmail (online) editor has an option for linking text.

Comment: Yes you are right then this #SomeText is not turning to hyperlink automatically which it should. Only the URL part is turned into hyperlink.

Comment: Are you using Gmail in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

To do this: 
    [Visit W3Schools.com!](https://www.w3schools.com/).

Use this Html:

`<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>`

Comment: Still forgot the closing tag ^^

Comment: Not anymore!!:)

Comment: Yes I am doing this what are you suggesting but it is not turning into a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

The gmail  editor has an option for linking text,if that is what you asked.
Or you can do this in HTML

```
< a href="https://www.w3schools.com/"> Visit W3Schools! < /a >
```

Comment: Well, I have some text before and after the above mentioned html tag. I am using a third party app which just copy paste the data from excel file and paste it into email body. The problem is only with the hyper link which is not being created after sending the email. I don't know what to do with this problem now.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when the email body or part of your email body is compiled in an HTML escape mode. Either you are doing something wrong or just pushing the plain Text without compiling.

If the above doesn't help then try to share your code, library, etc you are using to achieve the task.

Answer (score -1):

Is your message set up to use HTML or is it set for "plain text". If you are in plain text mode you anchor tags will not work.